# hermes has error in release build of react-native 0.60.5

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I upgraded my react-native project from 0.59.4 to 0.60.5 and everything works well. I tried to take release build without Hermes and everything is ok but when I enabled Hermes option in `android/app/build.gradle` and tried to take release build, I got an error as below:

[image: a busy cat]

how to solve this problem and enable Hermes for my project?

Comment: If your question has been answered, please make sure to accept and vote up an answer for further references.

Comment: You should put the error trace as text. Not only the image trace looks of low quality also it's not searchable.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First, try to clean the `node_modules` and install it again via `yarn`.

This issue has been fixed in [this PR](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/pull/25598).

You can also fix it by changing the `android/app/build.gradle` to:

```sh
project.ext.react = [
    ...
    hermesCommand: "../../node_modules/hermesvm/%OS-BIN%/hermes",
    ...
]
```

---

### UPDATE

first add new hermes via:

`yarn add --dev hermes-engine@0.1.1`

then in `android/app/build.gradle`:

```sh
project.ext.react = [
    entryFile: "index.js",
    enableHermes: true,  // clean and rebuild if changing
    hermesCommand: "../../node_modules/hermes-engine/%OS-BIN%/hermes",
]
```

and also change this:

`def hermesPath = "../../node_modules/hermesvm/android/";`

to this:

`def hermesPath = "../../node_modules/hermes-engine/android/";`

then replace `node_module/react-native/react.gradle` with [this file](https://gist.github.com/zenz/efd1f68ee4099abf77550ac7984df2fd).

If you use Proguard/R8, add this to `android/app/proguard-rules.pro`:

`-keep class com.facebook.hermes.unicode.* { *; }`

then clean via `gradlew clean` and finally:

`gradlew assembleRelease`

Comment: @MohamadKh75 Why is this not documented?

Comment: Because it's fixed